# PostgreSQL procedural language "C" not found

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, keyword, capitalization, plr

I am trying to use the [PL/R](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/) procedural language in a PostgreSQL 9.2 database. I have installed the `plr` language and I am trying to add it to a database. When I run the command `CREATE EXTENSION plr;` I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  language "C" does not exist
STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION plr;
ERROR:  language "C" does not exist
```

When I list the available languages in the database with `select * from pg_language;` I get

```
 lanname  | lanowner | lanispl | lanpltrusted | lanplcallfoid | laninline | lanvalidator | lanacl 
 ----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------
  internal |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2246 | 
  c        |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2247 | 
  sql      |       10 | f       | t            |             0 |         0 |         2248 | 
  plpgsql  |       10 | t       | t            |         12514 |     12515 |        12516 | 
 (4 rows)
```

So there is a language `c` but it is not in capital letters (not sure if that makes a difference).

I am wondering why the `plr` extension does not find the `C` procedural language?

Comment: If the language isn't trusted, then you have to be a super-user to create functions (or languages) using the given language. Are you trying to do this from an account with superuser access?

Comment: Did you try specifying lower-case 'c'?  In strings, case tends to matter.  Outside strings, it does not usually.

Comment: I do have superuser status yes. But how could I specify the lower case 'c'?

Comment: Are you sure PL/R supports 9.2?

Comment: I think this has been fixed by Joe Conway in v.8.3.0.13.1 of PL/R.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are probably running into this change in PostgreSQL 9.2 (quoting the [release notes here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-2.html#AEN110228)):

> No longer forcibly lowercase procedural language names in CREATE
>   FUNCTION (Robert Haas)
>
> While unquoted language identifiers are still lowercased, strings and
>   quoted identifiers are no longer forcibly down-cased. Thus for example
>   CREATE FUNCTION ... LANGUAGE 'C' will no longer work; it must be
>   spelled 'c', or better omit the quotes.

It's also reflected in the [manual for `CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)

> **lang_name**
>
> The name of the language that the function is implemented in. Can be `SQL`, `C`, `internal`, or the name of a user-defined procedural
>   language. For backward compatibility, the name can be enclosed by
>   single quotes.

Quoting the language name has been discouraged since at least version 7.3 (maybe longer), but old habits die hard, obviously. Removing the quotes around `'C'` fixes the problem, arriving at: `LANGUAGE c` or `LANGUAGE C`.

`PL/R` wasn't ready for PostgreSQL 9.2 in that respect, judging from the [project page](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/).

#### Feedback from Joe Conway

Joe Conway left an answer that got deleted because it should be a comment. I paste it here for the general public who can't see deleted answers:

> I got the message, just haven't had the time to do a new PL/R release.
>   Look for it by December, but in the meantime the manual workaround
>   noted above is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with pg_collkey. I believe your situation may have the same solution. Here's what I did: There's a .sql file in your postgres extension directory that tells postgres how to install the extension. In my case, it's called pg_collkey--0.5.0.sql. You'll need to modify that sql file. On my system (using Mac OS X and Homebrew) the file is located at /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/pg_collkey--0.5.0.sql). It probably contains a capital "C" in the LANGUAGE clause, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION collkey (text, text, bool, int4, bool) RETURNS bytea
  LANGUAGE 'C' IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
  '$libdir/collkey_icu.so',
  'pgsqlext_collkey';
```

Change it to a lower-case 'c' and re-run the "CREATE EXTENSION pg_collkey;" command in psql:

```
psql -c 'CREATE EXTENSION pg_collkey;' my_database_name
```

Of course, you'll need to use "plr" instead of pg_collkey for the extension name.