# What does “LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE” mean?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, volatile

When I create or update a function or procedure in a Postgres database I see `LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE` at the end of function.
What does this mean and what is its purpose?

Comment: Note that quoting the language's name is deprecated and will give you an error in 9.2 you should use `LANGUAGE plpgsql` instead.

Answer (score 27):

From [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html):

> VOLATILE indicates that the function value can change even within a
>   single table scan, so no optimizations can be made. Relatively few
>   database functions are volatile in this sense; some examples are
>   random(), currval(), timeofday(). But note that any function that has
>   side-effects must be classified volatile, even if its result is quite
>   predictable, to prevent calls from being optimized away; an example is
>   setval().

Answer (score 9):

Not least, `LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE` means that somebody didn't get the memo.

The language name in [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) is an identifier and should not be quoted. Should be:

```
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Malpractice can lead to confusing errors. See:

- [PostgreSQL procedural language "C" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514664/postgresql-procedural-language-c-not-found/12530268#12530268)

About function volatility:

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)