# How to write a function using arrays as input parameter in postgres 8.2

Tags: arrays, postgresql, multivalue, greenplum, postgresql-8.2

I am fairly new to Postgres and would like help with writing function that has an array as input parameter. I am using the function for a SSRS report and would like to add multiselect functionality

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(facid bigint, dptname text[])
RETURNS SETOF tmpdb AS
$BODY$
select * from tblitem
where dptname = $2 and facid = $1
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

In the dptname you can choose either dress or shoes but would like to display result set of choosing both. 
VARIADIC is not an option because of the version.

Comment: If this is for SQL Server Reporting Services, then why are you using Postgres? Or what's SSRS supposed to mean? And if you are using Postgres, why the [long dead and forgotten version 8.2](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)?

Comment: company politics I guess. But that is the environment I have to work with

Comment: How do Postgres and SSRS go together?

Comment: they had a SQL server backend but they are migrating everything to greenplum.

Comment: That's the kind of information that should be in the question. Especially since Greenplum is *not* Postgres. It's just based on Postgres.

Comment: note to self @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(facid bigint, dptname text[])
   RETURNS SETOF tblitem AS
$BODY$
select * from tblitem
where  facid = $1
and    dptname = ANY($2)
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

- [`ANY` should work in Postgres 8.2.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/functions-comparisons.html)
- The function can be `STABLE`.

  - [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)
- While you `SELECT * FROM tblitem`, the function should return `SETOF tblitem`.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried ANY yesterday.. ANYway, it worked! Thanks for saving me a rewrite! and some good info on stable