# Error while trying to insert data into timestamp field using plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, plpgsql

I have the following `plpgsql` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(OUT pid bigint)
    RETURNS bigint AS
  $BODY$
    DECLARE
      current_time timestamp with time zone = now();
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO "TEST"(
        created)
        VALUES (current_time) RETURNING id INTO pid;
    END
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from test_func();
```

The above gives an error:

> ```
> column "created" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type time with time zone
> ```

Insertion query without function:

```
INSERT INTO "TEST"(
        created)
        VALUES (now()) RETURNING id INTO pid;
```

or if `now()` is used directly without defining variable it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`CURRENT_TIME`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is a [**reserved word**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) (and a special function), you cannot use it as variable name. You don't need a variable here to begin with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(OUT pid bigint) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO "TEST"(created)
   VALUES (now())
   RETURNING id
   INTO   pid;
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`now()` is a `STABLE` function. It does not change across the same transaction. There is no need to capture the result into a variable.

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)