# PostgreSQL: No function matches the given name and argument types

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, procedure

I have the following procedure:

```
DROP FUNCTION presAdress();

CREATE FUNCTION presadress() RETURNS VARCHAR(100) AS $$
DECLARE studioName text;
    BEGIN

    RETURN (
    SELECT address AS pres_address
    FROM MovieExec
    WHERE cert# IN (
        SELECT presC# 
        FROM Studio
        WHERE name = studioName)
        );
    END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I try to run the procedure:

```
select presadress('Paramount');
```

But I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: function presadress(text) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 294
```

I suspect that this is because there is some kind of error regarding the in parameters of the procedure, but I have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: You have declared the function to take no arguments.  Hence, when you pass an argument, the function has no definition.

Comment: So how do I reformulate it to take in a string of arbitrary length? I thought this was done in the 'DECLARE studioName text;' line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a declaration more like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION presadress (v_studioName text)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(100) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN(SELECT address AS pres_address
           FROM MovieExec
           WHERE cert# IN (SELECT presC# 
                           FROM Studio
                           WHERE name = v_studioName)
         );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function parameter, like @Gordon demonstrates, but you don't need plpgsql for this at all. And the query can simplified (shorter, faster):

```
CREATE FUNCTION presadress(_studioname text)
  RETURNS text AS
$$
SELECT m.address
FROM   studio s
JOIN   movieexec m ON m.cert# = s.presc#
WHERE  s.name = _studioname
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Function volatility can be `STABLE`.

Related:

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)
- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)
- [PostgreSQL Stored Procedure Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684)