# Calculation in nested plpgsql function slower than in query directly?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, sql-execution-plan

I have a table with some `text` and some `numeric` columns, e.g.:

```
dimension_1, dimension_2, counter_1, counter_2
```

and instead of performing the query

```
SELECT dimension_1, dimension_2, (counter_1, NULLIF(counter_2, 0)) as kpi 
from table order by kpi desc nulls last;
```

I want to create a function and do:

```
SELECT dimension_1, dimension_2, func(counter_1, counter_2) as kpi
from table order by kpi desc nulls last;
```

I used the following implementation in Postgres:

```
CREATE FUNCTION kpi_latency_ext_msec(val1 numeric, val2 numeric)     
RETURNS numeric AS $func$
BEGIN

RETURN ($1 / NULLIF($2, 0::numeric));             

END; $func$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL SECURITY DEFINER IMMUTABLE;
```

and get the desired result but with slower performance.

From `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` I get:

**1st query (with func):**

```
Sort  (cost=800.85..806.75 rows=2358 width=26) (actual  time=5.534..5.710 rows=2358 loops=1)
Sort Key: (kpi_latency_ext_msec(external_tcp_handshake_latency_sum, external_tcp_handshake_latency_samples))
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 281kB
 ->  Seq Scan on counters_by_cgi_rat  (cost=0.00..668.76 rows=2358 width=26) (actual time=0.142..4.233 rows=2358 loops=1)
Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2018-05-10 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2018-05-13 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (granularity = '1 day'::interval))
Planning time: 0.221 ms
Execution time: 5.881 ms
```

**2nd query (no func):**

```
Sort  (cost=223.14..229.04 rows=2358 width=26) (actual time=1.933..2.114 rows=2358 loops=1)

Sort Key: ((external_tcp_handshake_latency_sum / NULLIF(external_tcp_handshake_latency_samples, 0::numeric)))
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 281kB
->  Seq Scan on counters_by_cgi_rat  (cost=0.00..91.06 rows=2358 width=26) (actual time=0.010..1.190 rows=2358 loops=1)
Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2018-05-10 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2018-05-13 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (granularity = '1 day'::interval))
Planning time: 0.139 ms
Execution time: 2.279 ms
```

Performing the queries without `ORDER BY`:

**No func:**

```
Seq Scan on table (cost=0.00..91.06 rows=2358 width=26) (actual time=0.016..1.223 rows=2358 loops=1)
```

**With func:**

```
Seq Scan on table (cost=0.00..668.76 rows=2358 width=26) (actual time=0.123..3.518 rows=2358 loops=1)
```

**RESULTS** for function **no SECURITY DEFINER**

```
Seq Scan on counters_by_cgi_rat  (cost=0.00..668.76 rows=2358 width=26) 
                                  (actual time=0.035..3.718 rows=2358 loops=1)
Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2018-05-10 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) 
        AND ("timestamp" < '2018-05-13 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) 
        AND (granularity = '1 day'::interval))
  Planning time: 0.086 ms
  Execution time: 3.923 ms
```

**RESULTS** for plain query

```
Seq Scan on counters_by_cgi_rat  (cost=0.00..91.06 rows=2358 width=26)    
                                 (actual time=0.017..1.175 rows=2358 loops=1)  
Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2018-05-10 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) 
AND ("timestamp" < '2018-05-13 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)     
AND (granularity = '1 day'::interval))
 Planning time: 0.105 ms
 Execution time: 1.356 ms
```

**RESULTS** with language sql

```
 Seq Scan on counters_by_cgi_rat  (cost=0.00..91.06 rows=2358 width=26)          
                                  (actual time=0.011..1.123 rows=2358 loops=1)
 Filter: (("timestamp" >= '2018-05-10 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) 
         AND ("timestamp" < '2018-05-13 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) 
         AND (granularity = '1 day'::interval))
 Planning time: 0.180 ms
 Execution time: 1.294 ms
```

**FAST ENOUGH** with language sql

For sure it is faster than using language **plpgsql** but slightly slower than the original query (after repeated runs)

**========= UPDATE =========**

```
CREATE FUNCTION kpi_latency_ext_msec(val1 numeric, val2 numeric)
RETURNS numeric LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
'SELECT $1 / NULLIF($2, 0)';
```

Best results obtained with the above function (even faster than the plain query)

Answer (score 3):

The poison dart is **`SECURITY DEFINER`**. Functions declared `SECURITY DEFINER` cannot be inlined - and enforce a context switch if I am not mistaken. That can make them **considerably more expensive**. There is really no need for `SECURITY DEFINER` in the example. You do not need different privileges for the simple calculation. (Maybe your actual use case is different.)

And there is no need for PL/pgSQL either. **Only SQL functions** can be inlined - if some additional preconditions are met.

Since all used functions are `IMMUTABLE`, you should declare the function **`IMMUTABLE`**. (Default function volatility is `VOLATILE`.) You already updated the question accordingly. That allows expression indexes and can help prevent repeated evaluation in some situations. But it ***never*** helps with function inlining. Au contraire: it imposes more preconditions (which are met in this case). Quoting the [Postgres Wiki on function inlining](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) (last update 2016 at the time of writing):

> if the function is declared `IMMUTABLE`, then the expression must not
>   invoke any non-immutable function or operator

Quoting [Tom Lane on pgsql-performance](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12240.1376507119%40sss.pgh.pa.us):

> The basic point here is that a function marked volatile can be
>   expanded to its contained functions even if they're immutable; but the
>   other way around represents a potential semantic change, so the
>   planner won't do it.

#### Solution

Try without `SECURITY DEFINER`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION kpi_latency_ext_msec(val1 numeric, val2 numeric)     
  RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN $1 / NULLIF($2, numeric '0');
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Should be *much* faster already.

Or radically simplify to an SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_div0_sql_nullif(val1 numeric, val2 numeric)     
  RETURNS numeric LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$SELECT $1 / NULLIF($2, numeric '0')$$;
```

Faster, yet?

Related:

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)

#### Benchmark

I used `IF` and `CASE` expressions at first, but after [a_horse_with_no_name's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327898/calculation-in-nested-plpgsql-function-slower-than-in-query-directly#comment87694328_50336079) I ran extensive tests showing `NULLIF` to be slightly faster. So I simplified to the original `NULLIF` variant accordingly.

<sub>The major points are still no `SECURITY DEFINER`, `SQL` and `IMMUTABLE`.</sub>

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=80057da48ef0d3697e83369067f6cf2c) - pg 10
db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=80057da48ef0d3697e83369067f6cf2c) - pg 9.4

Comment: I would probably simplify that to: `select $1 / nullif($2, 0)` - would a `case` faster in that case?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I ran some tests and found you are right: `NULLIF` seems to be slightly faster. Added results above.

Comment: Using nullif and define function as STABLE has better performance than the plain query

Comment: @dimitrislepipas: `STABLE` and `IMMUTABLE` should result in the same performance for this function in your case. (I actually tested.) But `IMMUTABLE` is generally preferable *if applicable* since it has other benefits. It can be used in an expression index etc.