# postgREST route using function does not update table

Tags: postgresql, supabase, postgrest

I am using Supabase which has a built in postgREST server.
In this server **I have created a function that should update a value** given a checksum:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_value(_id TEXT, _value INTEGER, _check INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
  IF get_checksum(_value) = _check THEN
    UPDATE values_table SET score = _value WHERE device_id = _id;
    RETURN TRUE;
  ELSE
    RETURN FALSE;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- the schema is reloading after creating a function according to the docs
NOTIFY pgrst, 'reload schema';
```

When I call this function **via sql** everything works cheerio and I get the `TRUE` response, and I can see **the value is updated in the table**

```sql
SELECT * FROM set_value('SOME_ID', 123, 123456)
-- | Results |
-- | true    |
```

However, calling this **via api** does not seem to work. I get the correct responses (true when checksum matches, false otherwise), but **the value in the table remains unchanged.**

I am using the POST request below, which according to the [documentation](https://postgrest.org/en/latest/api.html#immutable-and-stable-functions), should run in a read/write transaction.

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://<myapp>.supabase.co/rest/v1/rpc/set_value' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <mytoken>' \
--header 'apiKey: <mykey>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "_id": "_deviceId",
    "_value": 123,
    "_check": 123456
}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce with the example you gave (without using `get_checksum`). I suggest you try to debug by simplifying the function, doing first an UPDATE and then adding the conditionals to see where it fails exactly. And the `set_value` function returns `BOOL` right? It says `TRUE` in the example.

Comment: @LaurenceIsla yes, it returns a bool, that was a typo. I will give a shot at simplifying

Comment: I cannot find anyone with this problem. I created a new function with no no checksum, no variables, no conditional, nothing but a simple update, and despite receiving the correct return value, it simply does nothing. It could be permissions or the request itself?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `volatile` to the function creation in order for it to perform an update on the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_value(_id TEXT, _value INTEGER, _check INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN
  IF get_checksum(_value) = _check THEN
    UPDATE values_table SET score = _value WHERE device_id = _id;
    RETURN TRUE;
  ELSE
    RETURN FALSE;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql volatile;
```

You can read more about the volatile keyword in this other SO answer [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)

Comment: After some investigation, I am not 100% yet if it is because of `VOLATILE` but I had to add `SECURITY DEFINER` as well. I will confirm once I have fully tested. Related: https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/discussions/2387