# Postgres: add the same timestamp to all rows in a select query

Tags: postgresql

is there a way to add the same unix timestamp to all the rows in a select statement in PostgreSQL?

The purpose is to have the **same value for all the rows** - regards how long it runs.

When running the following query - if the query takes long (couple of seconds for millions of rows) then some rows will have a different timestamp.

```
select id, (extract(epoch from now())) as queryId from books;
```

Edit:
This is actually works

Comment: I find this hard to believe. `now()` is an alias for `transaction_timestamp()` which pins the time at the beginning of the transaction per [Current Datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). A test here with `select a, extract(epoch from now()) from generate_series(1, 10000000) as t(a);` that spanned 4.3 seconds showed no difference between the first and last row.  You will need to provide more information: 1) Postgres version(community or fork?). 2) OS and version.

Comment: You are right. I got different results due to a mistake I did.

Comment: Alright. At this point you should either: 1) Delete the question  or 2) Add information on what the mistake was so other people can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `SELECT` works as is.

`now()` is a stable function (volatility **`STABLE`**). Meaning, it's outcome never changes within the same `SELECT` statement. See:

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)
- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

Comment: Now() doesn't change within the same transaction either, even if the transaction takes seconds/hours/days you always get the same timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate the timestamp first and then select it for all the rows from the books table.

```
-- Generate the timestamp
WITH query_time AS (SELECT extract(epoch from now()) AS query_timestamp)

-- Use it in your SELECT statement for all the rows
SELECT id, query_timestamp FROM books, query_time
```

Comment: That's unnecessary.

Comment: Strange answer, NOW() does that already, there is no point in trying to do it twice. `These SQL-standard functions all return values based on the start time of the current transaction`. And `now() is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to transaction_timestamp().` see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT