# Building data/statistical graphs from postgres data?

Tags: postgresql

I have a single table which stores bandwidth usage on the network over a period of time. One column will contain the date time (primary key) the bandwidth is recorded and the other column will contain that actual bandwidth value.

I need to generate some graphs (pie charts, bar graphs etc) and other statistical graphs from this data. However, I would like to do generation of the data on the database server rather than return all the data to the client for it to process and generate the graph.

My question is are there any libraries or techniques which help do this in Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

this can be achieved by          R and PL/R     graphical development packages.

[refer](http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/Tidbits/bernier/art_66/graphingWithR.html)

Comment: At the time being [PL/R does not seem to be ready for PostgreSQL 9.2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12530268/939860). Should work with 9.1 or earlier, though.

Comment: I don't need the generation of the graphs as my client (flex or silverlight) will render the graph. Can I still use PL/R or do I have to write the queries myself?