# Create Function Failed in Postgres - language C Does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shortest_path(
                      sql text, 
                      source_id integer, 
                      target_id integer, 
                      directed boolean, 
                      has_reverse_cost boolean)
    RETURNS SETOF path_result
    AS '$libdir/librouting'
    LANGUAGE 'C' IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

When I try to Create a Function like the above I am getting a error like  language C Does not exist

Postgres Version 9.3 x86
PostGIS Version - postgis Bundle Version 2.1(with pgrouting 2.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514664/postgresql-procedural-language-c-not-found. Basically, change the C to a c and reload the function definition.

Comment: The language name is an **identifier** not a string value. So you should **not** use single quotes for it. `language c` should work just fine. Using single quotes to specify the language is a deprecated feature that is only supported for backwards compatibility.

Comment: yes now i figured out